# Detect mobile client in webgl

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need to detect whether the user is running a webgl app in a mobile browser or on a desktop/laptop browser. Is this possible to detect using the Unity API, or you need to do some HTML hack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a "hack" for this. You can find out via JavaScript so you just need a [plugin connection](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html) between the c# and JavaScript e.g. using the [`Navigator.userAgent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/userAgent) somewhat like

```js
var HandleIO = {
    IsMobilePlatform : function()
    {
        var userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
        isMobile = (
                    /\b(BlackBerry|webOS|iPhone|IEMobile)\b/i.test(userAgent) ||
                    /\b(Android|Windows Phone|iPad|iPod)\b/i.test(userAgent) ||
                    // iPad on iOS 13 detection
                    (userAgent.includes("Mac") && "ontouchend" in document)
                );
        return isMobile;
    }
};
mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, HandleIO);
```

put this e.g. in a folder like `Assets/WebGL/Plugins` an make sure to only compile it for WebGL

[image]

and then on the c# side you could include like e.g.

```csharp
using System;
#if UNITY_WEBGL
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
#endif
using UnityEngine;

public class WebGLBrowserCheck : MonoBehaviour
{
#if UNITY_WEBGL
    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    static extern bool IsMobilePlatform();

    public static bool IsMobileBrowser()
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        return false; // value to return in Play Mode (in the editor)
#elif UNITY_WEBGL
        return IsMobilePlatform(); // value based on the current browser
#else
        return false;
#endif
    }
#endif
}
```

so later on you just call

```
var isMobile = WebGLBrowserCheck.IsMobileBrowser();
```

*Of course there are more mobile phones and OS then the listed ones so you might want to extend it if needed but these should cover the most common ones*

Answer (score -2):

I think you are after [preprocessor directives](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html). They take place before compiling your code to pre-select the code that needs to be run according the platform you are working building on. Thats why they're also called conditional compilation directives.

For example:

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR || UNITY_WEBGL
 //this code will be compiled and run while in editor or webgl build target in the build settings
#endif

#if UNITY_ANDROID 
 //this code will be compiled and run when the build target is set to android in the build settings
#endif
```

To detect which device your app is running in in the browser you need to use  the [Navigator.userAgent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/userAgent)
Check also the [windowNavigator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/navigator)

You can check out also libraries that do that for you, such as [this](https://github.com/kaimallea/isMobile)

Comment: This works on c# side only and only allows to differ between WebGL and Android as a build target platform .... OP's target platform is always going to be WebGL .. the question is how to determine on what device this WebGL is being executed