# Check if android or iOS or PC WebGL

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webgl

I have a code to check if the device is a mobile or not in my WebGL application. I want to improve this code to detect if the mobile is iOS or Android. How can I do this?

Plugin.jslib

```
 var MyPlugin = {
     IsMobile: function()
     {
         return UnityLoader.SystemInfo.mobile;
     }
 };
 
 mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, MyPlugin);
```

Unity:

```
     [DllImport("__Internal")]
     private static extern bool IsMobile();
 
     public bool isMobile()
     {
         #if !UNITY_EDITOR && UNITY_WEBGL
             return IsMobile();
         #endif
         return false;
     }
```

Comment: Surely simple conditional compiles work here. As you cant run each on anything other than its intended target. Its not like compiling for windows and running it under wine or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@LoïcLeGrosFrère's answer is quite working, but it needs to be supported and there is additional overhead for regex evaluation.

Unity engine already determines operating system family and code can be like this:

Unity:

```
    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern bool isAndroid();

    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern bool isIos();
    
    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern string getOperationSystemFamilyName();

    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern void freeBuffer(string ptr);

    public bool IsAndroid()
    {
#if !UNITY_EDITOR && UNITY_WEBGL
        return isAndroid()
#else
        return false;
#endif
    }
    
    public bool IsIos()
    {
#if !UNITY_EDITOR && UNITY_WEBGL
        return isIos()
#else
        return false;
#endif
    }
    
    public string GetOperationSystemFamilyName()
    {
#if !UNITY_EDITOR && UNITY_WEBGL
        var os = getOperationSystemFamilyName();
        var copy = String.Copy(os);
        freeBuffer(os);
        return copy;
        
#else
        return SystemInfo.operatingSystem;
#endif
    }
```

js:

```
mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, {
  isAndroid : function() {
    return Module.SystemInfo.os === "Android";
  },

  isIos : function() {
    return Module.SystemInfo.os === "iPhoneOS" || Module.SystemInfo.os === "iPadOS" || Module.SystemInfo.os === "macOS";
  },
  
  getOperationSystemFamilyName: function() {
    var os = Module.SystemInfo.os;
    var bufferSize = lengthBytesUTF8(os) + 1;
    var buffer = _malloc(bufferSize);
    stringToUTF8(os, buffer, bufferSize);
    return buffer;
  }, 

  freeBuffer: function(ptr) {
    _free(ptr);
  }
});
```

**malloc** and **free** are very expensive. It is best way to allocate the buffer once, at startup for example, and release it when the application ends.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72084050/12933771)
It seem you can do something like :

```
var MyPlugin = {
    IsMobile: function()
    {
        return UnityLoader.SystemInfo.mobile;
    },
    IsIOSPlatform : function()
    {
        var userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
        isIOS = (
                    /\b(iPhone)\b/i.test(userAgent) ||
                    /\b(iPad|iPod)\b/i.test(userAgent) ||
                    // iPad on iOS 13 detection
                    (userAgent.includes("Mac") && "ontouchend" in document)
                );
        return isIOS;
    },
    IsAndroidPlatform : function()
    {
        var userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
        isAndroid = (
                    /\b(Android)\b/i.test(userAgent)
                );
        return isAndroid;
    }
};
```

Comment: Unity engine already determines operating system family. Try use the property Module.SystemInfo.os, like Module.SystemInfo.os === "Android" for android devices and (Module.SystemInfo.os === "iPhoneOS" || Module.SystemInfo.os === "iPadOS" || Module.SystemInfo.os === "macOS") for iOS instead of regular expressions.

Comment: @stazik so you are saying i can completely do it in C# code instead of using javascript?